# Há uma tradução melhor para "signal word" do que "palavra sinal"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, tradução-inglês, estrangeirismos

Estou traduzindo um manual técnico (não sou tradutora, só estou traduzindo porque calha de eu trabalhar com esse produto e falar português).

Por exemplo, na frase:

> As advertências começam com *palavras-sinais*, que expressam o nível do perigo.

Como posso substituir “palavra-sinais”?

Comment: @william lio, aprovei parte da tua edição, mas no parêntese mantive a formulação original: creio que com o original "calha de eu..." a autora quer dizer mesmo isso, "por acaso, acontece eu trabalhar.."), e não "convém que eu trabalhe..." [(Aulete 1, e não Aulete 3)](http://www.aulete.com.br/calhar); e como aquilo é um aparte, até faz mais sentido estar entre parênteses do que separado por travessão. A Mrs Bighead poderá esclarecer qual das nossas interpretações está correta. Mas na dúvida mantém-se o original.

Comment: Mrs Bighead, eu acho que compreendo o que são essas "palavras-sinais" (e não me ocorre nada melhor), mas talvez não se perdesse mais contexto e explicação mais completa do que são exatamente essas "signal words".

Comment: Que tal "palavras de sinalização"? Geralmente *signal words* são palavras como "cuidado" e "atenção", que precedem o aviso, é o caso aqui, Mrs Bighead?

Comment: @william lio, se bem que eu também não usaria *calhar* daquela maneira: eu uso *calhar* para acontecimentos ("calhou eu estar trabalhando"), mas não para situações habituais (como trabalhar em geral ou falar português).

Comment: @Jacinto, de fato, existe uma ambiguidade específica a esse tipo de construção para o verbo calhar; podem-se ser 'ocorrer por acaso' ou 'convir', mas suponho que seja apenas um uso estranho do 'ocorrer por acaso' mesmo. Quanto aos parênteses, com efeito que semanticamente esses façam mais sentido; porém, por ser uma sútil nuance, optei por substituir pelo travessão, pois fica mais limpo visualmente.

Answer (score 1):

O [Linguee](https://www.linguee.pt/ingles-portugues/traducao/signal+word.html) sugere **palavra-sinal** e, sem hífen, essa é também a expressão usada no artigo [Perigo, cuidado, atenção: a comunicação linguística de risco em advertências de produtos](http://periodicos.unb.br/index.php/les/article/view/9808).

Mas, se a expressão não agrada, o Linguee também menciona **palavra de sinalização**, que talvez soe mais natural.

Answer (score 1):

Na língua inglesa é comum o uso de termos que tornam difícil a tradução em poucas palavras.

Se "signal word" quiser expressar que o início do texto começa com uma palavra de advertência tais como: ATENÇÃO, CUIDADO, PERIGO, VOCÊ VAI MORRER, talvez a frase possa ser escrita da seguinte forma:

"As advertências começam com **interjeições** que expressam o nível do perigo."

Tirando a vírgula evita-se a redundância e explica de que tipo é a interjeição.

Answer (score 1):

*Signal words* são palavras que servem de guia, para facilitar o entendimento prévio de uma mensagem. Por exemplo, a palavra **Atenção** transmite a ideia de que o que há por vir merece ser tratado atentamente. Neste contexto, eu usaria **palavras-chaves**.

> As advertências começam com palavras-chaves, que expressam o nível do
>   perigo.